# jQuery ui Dialog content via ajax not displaying on asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I want a dialog created dynamically when page load on asp.net. Via javascript I am doing something like this:

```
Popup.Selector = {
   if($('#DivDialogSelector1').length == 0){
      $('body').append('<div id="DivDialogSelector1"></div>');
      $.ajax({
         method:'Get',
         url:'../Selectors/Clients.aspx',
         success: function (data) {
            $('#DivDialogSelector1').append(data);
            $('#DivDialogSelector1').dialog({
               title: 'Select Client',
                    autoOpen: false,
                    'Select': function () {
                        $(config.Code).val();
                        $(config.Name).val();
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    },
                    'Cancel': function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
            });
         }
      });
      $(config.fires).click(function(){
         $('#DivDialogSelector1').dialog("open");
      });
   }
}
```

But when on my defaultPage.aspx I set this javascript it doesn't works.
But doesn't show any error on the console.log

I checked if I put the reference to the script on the head tag and it's there. So I don't have any idea of what is happening

Comment: Doesn't display the dialog when I click the fires object (html element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an answer directly, but a few steps to help debug this.

1. Check that your click is definitely firing (put an alert() in your click handler)
2. In Firebug, check that DivDialogSelector1 has the correct HTML which is dynamically loaded from the server.
3. If the answer to 2 is no, then make sure that your GET URL is correct (hard-code an absolute path to test)